# Python re.findall() doesn't work with optional matching (using question mark)

Tags: python, regex

According to an online tutorial which I am reading, it is stated that:

**Optional Matching with the Question Mark**

"Sometimes there is a pattern that you want to match only optionally. That is, the regex should find a match whether or not that bit of text is there. The ? character flags the group that precedes it as an optional part of the pattern. For example, enter the following into the interactive shell:"

```
>>> batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(wo)?man')
>>> mo1 = batRegex.search('The Adventures of Batman')
>>> mo1.group()
'Batman'
```

**My Problem:**

I am trying to find matching phone numbers, in the form of either `123-456-7890` (without country code) or `(111)-123-456-7890` (with country code).

Here is my regex code for python to return a list of matching phone numbers:

```
phone_num_regex = re.compile(r'(\(\d{3}\)-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
phone_num_list = phone_num_regex.findall('800-420-7240 (933)-415-863-9900 415-863-9950')
```

However, the phone_num_list I obtained is `['', '(933)-', '']` instead of what I wanted which is `['800-420-7240, '(933)-415-863-9900', '415-863-9950']`.

May I know what is wrong with my code? I'm guessing it's something to do with the '?' (optional matches)

Comment: Try to make the first a non capturing group `(?:\(\d{3}\)-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: Note that You should generally prefer to split this into groups of phone numbers first (just `str.split` should do this) and then match on each number. That lets you get a little more creative with your final regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including your optional sections in capture groups, which means that all `re.findall` gives you is those groups.

If you use non-capturing groups instead, this won't happen.

```
re.compile(r'(?:\(\d{3}\)-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

> `(...)`
>       Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the `\number` special sequence, described below. To match the literals `'('` or `')'`, use `\(` or `\)`, or enclose them inside a character class: `[(]`, `[)]`.

> `(?:...)`
>       A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>       Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

(emphasis mine)